# alert before executing switch case

Tags: javascript

I have switch statement like this

```
switch(action) {
 case "remove":
 queryString = 'action='+action+'&code='+ product_code;
 break;
}
```

How can use alert "Are you sure?" before executing "remove".if user clicks no, "remove" should not be processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case "remove":
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        /* your code... */
    }
    break;
```

Comment: This is a good way to approach things as it allows you to tailor the text of the question according to the specific task.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Use Confirm.

```
  switch(action) {
  case "remove":
   var r = confirm("Are you sure");
  if (r == true) {
  queryString = 'action='+action+'&code='+ product_code;
 break;
     } else {
     break;
            } 

          }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`window.comfirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) method, which returns a [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) value according to the users choice.

```
/* open confirmation box */
var yes = confirm('Are you sure?');
/* act accordingly */
if (yes) {
    switch(action) {
        /* etc etc */
    }
} else {
    /* do something else */
}
```